# LaTeX-Package hf-tikz: Error message "Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!"

Tags: tikz-pgf, hf-tikz

The package hf-tikz is great for putting a frame around an equation. Although I am not absolutely sure there seems to be a "new" error massage when using this package: "Missing character: There is no ; in font nullfont!"

I stripped my complex beamer-file down to actually a minimal LaTeX-file which also gives the error message:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}
% \font\nullfont=cmr10
\begin{document}
\begin{displaymath}
  \tikzmarkin{eq}
  c^2 = a^2+b^2
  \tikzmarkend{eq}
\end{displaymath}
\end{document}
```

The resulting PDF-file is ok with no errors, but the error message makes me a bit nervous because the question is always what happens after the next update? My system is a MINT Linux 21.1 with an underlying Ubuntu 22.04 and a full installation of Texlive 2022.

If I uncomment the line "% \font\nullfont=cmr10" a semicolon appears at the end of the coloured box. From other postings about the "Missing character..." error message I learned that setting the nullfont to a visible font allows to find the error in the underlying LaTeX code. It seems that there is an error in the package hf-tikz or that the syntax of tikz has changed a little bit and the older package hf-tikz has not been adapted to these changes.

Any idea how to overcome the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case the message is harmless. It was always in the log but appears now also on the terminal because `\tracinglostchars` has been set to 2 in a current LaTeX.

But it would be better if hf-tikz would avoid it by delimiting the `\tikz` arguments by braces instead of using the semicolon syntax, as with it there is always the danger to end up with one stray semicolon too much:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hf-tikz}

\renewcommand\tikzmarkend[2][]{%
\tikz[remember picture with id=#2]{#1}} %{#1} instead of #1;

\begin{document}

\begin{displaymath}
 \tikzmarkin{eq}
 c^2 = a^2+b^2
 \tikzmarkend{eq}
\end{displaymath}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast & complete answer! It seems that hf-tikz needs some care but since the latest version is almost ten years old it is in question if the package is still being maintained?

Comment: no idea, write to the author and look what happens.

Comment: Already did that after your answer:-) -- let's see if the author is still active

Comment: Nice guy, he already answered and will take a closer look at the problem in the next days / weeks :-)